# How to design a crystal oscillator circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, oscillator, crystal

I need to produce a 32.768KHz frequency for a binary counter but I have no idea how to design a crystal oscillator circuit.

I tried multiple simulations in Proteus 8 but always failed in making it oscillate.

Can you please tell how should one generate an oscillating signal for a circuit?

I am trying to use a [74HCT93 counter.](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/cd74hc93)

[image: Circuit pic]

Comment: 1. Your ground source symbol is missing yet IC1 Vcc is connected to it.. Just pick a 32kHz clock chip

Comment: Due to the high Q factor of a crystal, it is practically impossible to simulate the crystal oscillator's behavior in a time (transient) simulation. It can be done by making a model with the same losses (same R) but different L and C so that Q becomes lower. I have done this many times. Also, you need to apply a starting pulse to get the oscillation going as with all simulated oscillators. If you've never simulated an (non-crystal) oscillator before  then this will be a challenge.

Comment: But since you're designing for a PCB, you can just build the oscillator on a breadboard. A "Pierce oscillator" would be a good start. Look up some schematics for a 32 kHz oscillator and build the same. If you still need to simulate then in the simulator use a 32 kHz sine / square wave voltage source instead of the crystal oscillator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulating crystal oscillator circuits is notoriously difficult.  I've seen it done in a demo but never had much luck with it myself.

Usually you want something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzl7t3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The (usually) most critical part is the values of the two caps.  You'll want to read the data sheet for the crystal you choose.

Comment: That circuit needs much more details to be a working circuit. As it is, it will never work. All the other parts are critical too, if not even more critical than the caps.

Comment: Hence the "something like this"...

Comment: Add 1M across inverter for self bias and series R to Xtal around a few or 5k for unknown 50uW power limit on xtal

Comment: The values Tony quotes are about right for standard crystals. For these 32768 Hz tuning fork crystals, the values are typically about a decade higher, as they operate at about 1 microwatt. And the inverter type is extremely important that it is not a buffered inverter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a Schmitt Trigger Oscillator. It may not be as accurate as you need but it may be easier if you have the parts. Otherwise I second @ Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75, just get a chip. It is way easier. BTW here is a picture of your schematic with some corrections. Hope it helps and I didn't mess it up.[image].